# How do I load remote script in jQuery noConflict mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to load a remote script which is not utilizing jQuery noConflict mode from a WordPress website, which is. Effectively I need to wrap the remote script in noConflict mode. I thought something like this would do the trick, but apparently not.

```
<script>
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.getScript('http://remote-domain.com/load/remote/script');
  });
</script>
```

I thought this would be straightforward, but couldn't see anything for remote scripts on Googling and checking other Stack Overflow questions. Is it possible? Am I missing something? Am I just being dim?

[See this CodePen](http://codepen.io/rhecil-codes/pen/AXyvja) featuring the actual script I am having issues with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No conflict should be done one once before all scripts. I see no other problems in your code.

But keep in mind, that jQuery will do an AJAX request for this file and you use a remote URL. There might be problems when your browser and/or server dosesn't allow this.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.getScript('http://remote-domain.com/load/remote/script');
});
```

Comment: No conflict is done before that, but I'm still getting a `TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$("#INJECTION-PLACEHOLDER")', '$' is undefined)` in the console, where `<div id="INJECTION-PLACEHOLDER"></div>` is the target for script injection from the remote script. I thought it must be something to do with noConflict. Could this be something else?

Comment: How about use `jQuery` instead of `$`? `jQuery.getScript('...');`

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately; but thanks for your suggestion. Will post an answer when I eventually solve it.

Comment: A big thanks for your time on this already. I've put this in a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/rhecil-codes/pen/AXyvja). Would you mind taking a quick look when you have a moment, even if just to confirm the issue is what we think it is?

Comment: How should this work? When you set `jQuery.noConflict();` the `$` is no longer available. And your included script uses `$` but can't find it anymore. You have to change the `$` to `jQuery` then in your script file.

Comment: Thanks. OK, I thought so - that was the question. The script is provided by a third party and I have no control over it. So there is no way to mask the $ from the client side?

Comment: What do you mean by "mask the $ from the client side"?

Comment: As in, parse the remote script in noConflict mode, equivalent to wrapping with `(function( $ ) {
  $(function() { // remote script code   });
})(jQuery);` if I wrote it.

Comment: No, that will not work. Only if you edit or copy the code to your local instance.

Comment: OK. Thanks for all your help. I will see if the service provider can update their code as it should be written that way anyway.